# PathTransition in loop

Tags: java, class, arraylist, javafx, inner-classes

I have 8x8 Board, *where SIZE = 8 and moveHistory is ArrayList of javafx.geometry.Point2D*. Here is code :

```
private class ChessBoard extends Pane {
    ImageView knightImageView = new ImageView("image/knight.jpg");

    ChessBoard() {
        this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            startX = (int)(e.getX() / (getWidth() / SIZE));
            startY = (int)(e.getY() / (getHeight() / SIZE));
            resetMoveHistory();
            paint();
        });
    }

    protected void paint() {
        this.getChildren().clear();

        this.getChildren().add(knightImageView);
        knightImageView.setX(startX * getWidth() / SIZE);
        knightImageView.setY(startY * getHeight() / SIZE);
        knightImageView.setFitWidth(getWidth() / SIZE);
        knightImageView.setFitHeight(getHeight() / SIZE);

        for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) {
            this.getChildren().add(new Line(0, i * getHeight() / SIZE,
                    getWidth(), i * getHeight() / SIZE));
            this.getChildren().add(new Line(i * getWidth() / SIZE, 0,
                    i * getWidth() / SIZE, getHeight()));
        }

        if (moveHistory != null) {
            for (int i = 1; i < moveHistory.size(); i++) {
                Point2D p1 = moveHistory.get(i - 1);
                Point2D p2 = moveHistory.get(i);
                PathTransition ptMove = new PathTransition();
                Line line = (new Line(
                        p1.getX() * (getWidth() / SIZE) + getWidth() / SIZE / 2,
                        p1.getY() * (getHeight() / SIZE) + (getHeight() / SIZE / 2),
                        p2.getX() * (getWidth() / SIZE) + getWidth() / SIZE / 2,
                        p2.getY() * (getHeight() / SIZE) + getHeight() / SIZE / 2));
                ptMove.setPath(line);
                ptMove.setNode(knightImageView);
                ptMove.setCycleCount(1);
                ptMove.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
                ptMove.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is display the moves with last loop, but it only shows 1 incorrect move and keeps playing it over and over. *Where am I going wrong?* **Any help would be greatly appriecated!**

Comment: could you include the code of the `resetMoveHistory()` method? since you are resetting before `paint()` every time you click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `play()` method starts the animation playing and exits immediately. So you effectively start all animations almost simultaneously, and let them all play concurrently. Each animation sets the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of your `knightImageView`, and these values will be set by each of the animations on each rendering frame during the duration of the animations. Whichever animation happens to set the values last will "win" on that frame, and that is the value that will be rendered. So the overall effect will be highly unpredictable.

What you want (I think) is to play one animation after the other. You can do this with a [`SequentialTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html). You code should probably look something like this:

```
if (moveHistory != null) {
    SequentialTransition sequentialTransition = new SequentialTranstiion();
    for (int i = 1; i < moveHistory.size(); i++) {
        Point2D p1 = moveHistory.get(i - 1);
        Point2D p2 = moveHistory.get(i);
        PathTransition ptMove = new PathTransition();
        Line line = (new Line(
                p1.getX() * (getWidth() / SIZE) + getWidth() / SIZE / 2,
                p1.getY() * (getHeight() / SIZE) + (getHeight() / SIZE / 2),
                p2.getX() * (getWidth() / SIZE) + getWidth() / SIZE / 2,
                p2.getY() * (getHeight() / SIZE) + getHeight() / SIZE / 2));
        ptMove.setPath(line);
        ptMove.setNode(knightImageView);
        ptMove.setCycleCount(1);
        ptMove.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        sequentialTransition.getChildren().add(ptMove);
    }
    sequentialTransition.play();
}
```

One other thing to note here is that the transition moves the image view by manipulating the `translateX` and `translateY` coordinates. The `setX` and `setY` methods of `ImageView` that you call probably don't do what you think: see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html).